# Как на php сохранять правильно дату используя mktime?

Tags: php

Есть простая форма:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="public_date" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Вводим будущую дату публикации, например, 25-12-2023 15:30:00

В базе данных поле public_date имеет тип **int**

При сохранении даты используется примерный код

```
$date = $_POST['public_date'];
[$d, $m, $y, $h, $M, $s] = sscanf($date, '%2d-%2d-%4d %2d:%2d:%2d');
$timeStamp = mktime($d, $m, $y, $h, $M, $s);
```

На локале date_default_timezone_get() показывает **UTC**

На сервере date_default_timezone_get() показывает **Europe/Moscow**

Из-за этого в базе данных на локале и на сервере в поле public_date разные значения.

Нашел решение вида, поставить

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Но не могу понять, это костыль или реально решение, что мне нужно?

Я хочу, чтобы в базе данных хранилась та дата, что я ввожу в поле public_date.

При этом не хотелось бы сломать работу сайта этой строкой date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
То есть чего я не могу понять, так это последствия указания UTC для сайта. По факту мой часовой пояс как раз таки совпадает с часовым поясом сервера.

Но на локале меня устраивает, что я вижу в базе то, что и в поле.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Comment: Вы можете объяснить, зачем в базе данных поле public_date имеет тип int?

Comment: Ипатьев, это старая cms, которая так спроектирована.

Comment: я не могу понять, в чем заключается проблема. Если полученное через mktime число сохранить в БД, а  потом запросить из нее обратно, то там будет ровно то же самое число. И та же самая дата. И при чем здесь "локал"?  Какая разница, что записано в БД на домашнем сервере?

Comment: Ипатьев, в $_POST['date'] = '15-10-2023 15:15' , из-за того, что на сервере UTC+3, то mktime сохраняет уже на 3 часа меньше время. И в БД сохраняется int на 3 часа меньше. То есть получается на фронте я отправляю одно время, а после сохранения в этоже поле на фронте получаю другое время.

Comment: Что я делаю не так? [Почему у меня int сохраняет то же самое время](https://3v4l.org/KOhva#v8.2.11)? Вы как-то используете этот int в запросах? И проблема в часовом поясе сервера базы данных? Почему тогда не пишете об этом, а про какой-то "локал"?

Comment: Вам нужно знать в какую зону конвертировать дату и время для клиентов, и хранить это на сервере. Обычно для этого сохраняют их зону и смещают дату и время на неё перед выдачей на фронт.

Comment: Ипатьев, посмотрите это https://3v4l.org/fn1as#v8.2.11 Именно mktime возвращает на 3 часа меньше, а не date

Answer (score -1):

Переменная `$m` повторяется и список параметров для `mktime` неправильный.

Попробуйте так:

```
$_POST['public_date'] = '25-12-2023 15:30:00'; // temp string

$date = $_POST['public_date'];
[$day, $month, $year, $h, $m, $s] = sscanf($date, '%2d-%2d-%4d %2d:%2d:%2d');
$timeStamp = mktime($h, $m, $s, $month, $day, $year);

echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $timeStamp); // temp string
```

Comment: Там была опечатка, для переменных был разный регистр букв. Исправил, спасибо. Вопрос скорее про timezone на сервере, что менять ли его или нет?

Comment: Установка `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` меняет `timezone` только для текущего скрипта.